# In the US, have there been any successful lawsuits over COVID infection liability?

Tags: united-states, liability, covid-19

Its often been claimed during the pandemic that some businesses voluntarily mandate masks because they fear losing a lawsuit if an employee or customer gets infected on their premises. Since March 2020, have any lawsuits of similar nature resulted in damages being awarded to the infected person?

Comment: Relevant in this context: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19-Pandemie_in_Ischgl (only available in German as detailed article). Ischgl (a skiing town in Austria) was where the pandemic took a big step in Europe, because allegedly reporting rules where broken. The article reports about large criminal investigations, but as of now, the cases where closed without any criminal accusations. Civil law cases are still open.

Comment: It would be also interesting to know what the typical time from injury to award is, especially when causality is sketchy.